# Tweetinvi - User.GetAuthenticatedUser is not being recognized by Visual Studio

Tags: tweetinvi

I am using Tweetinvi api in Visual Studio and trying to fetch my profile name and profile photo.I followed the documentation on git and was trying to replicate the same in my code ,however it is not recognizing the method GetAuthenticatedUser

var authenticateduser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();

I have seen some questions like this that said ,you need to give your keys to the method below, however i am doing that and am able to post and fetch tweets
 Auth.SetUserCredentials("key1",key2","key3,"key4")

This is my Pageload code

```
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

                    Auth.SetUserCredentials("key1",key2","key3,"key4")
        var authenticateduser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
        FetchTweets();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had imported Tweetinvi but somehow this particular function is not being picked up
so have to use code with

```
    var authenticateduser = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
    LblProfileName.Text = authenticateduser.Name;
    ImgProfile.ImageUrl = authenticateduser.ProfileImageUrl;
```